# Is there a way of making multiline snippet without the double quotes and commas every line?

Tags: visual-studio-code, editor

I think this is common to people who use snippets. Do anyone have any tips or suggestion for this one.

[image]

Sample image of my concern, as you can see, setting up multi-line snippets requires double quotes and commas on every line. It's not totally a hassle but maybe you have secret magic there you can share.

Answer (score 1):

The `body` of the snippet can take literal newlines and tabs.  So this works:

```
"body": ["echo '<pre>':\nprint_r($1);\n....etc."]
```

`\t` to insert a tab.

Comment: This is also an answer, Thank you very much @mark. But is there other way withouth those \n

Comment: And still be a multiple line?

Comment: No, either `\n` or on separate lines in the body like you had.